# Remove and reorder columns in gridview and persisting it on postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a page on which *GridView* is used to show records. Now I allowed the user to customize the *GridView* view by changing order of columns or adding removing columns from predefined list of columns. `OnPagePrerender` event I am removing all the cells from GridView and adding cells with the order selected by user. Its working fine but when a `PostBack` is occurred then it throws an exception i.e.

> Failed to load ViewState. etc.

Because now the cells are not the same as they were saved in `ViewState`.

What I want is to persist these changes that I have made to *GridView* on `PostBack`?

Comment: can you save the state of gridview ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the `GridView` (or your data recordset) in the `VIEWSTATE` and reload the `Gridview` **only from** the VIEWSTATE.

So in other words, only query the database when the data has to change, but you have to structure the `recordset` in a way that the `gridview` can display it, **the way the data has loaded**, ie dynamic SQL, with your order of columns as needed.

Then save the `recordset` into a `viewstate` variable, and refer to it in your `gridview` when a postback is made.

I did something similar with rows, not columns, and yeah you can't rely on the default `datasource` or `datasourceID` anymore when the `gridview` control is being manipulated at that deep level.

Comment: I did this but i have a large amount of data and if i keep it in viewstate i will increase the page load. I stored the collection in viewstate and rebind the gridview on PreLoad page event its working but the problem is the load time will be increased.

Comment: Yeah sorry, but that's the only way I know. Consider sourcing the data from XML, Json, or something that's quicker.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to create a new order of you Gridview columns.

First make copy of your columns. Second reorder your columns.

```
var columns = GridView1.Columns.CloneFields(); // makes a copy of gridview columns
GridView1.Columns.Clear(); // remove all the columns

// now make any order for your gridview columns
GridView1.Columns.Add(columns[3]); // e.g. now your column 4 is placed at first position
GridView1.Columns.Add(columns[0]); // here column 1 is placed at second position
```

Comment: I tried this its working but when i do a postback then data is removed from the cells. I am adding all columns only those columns are added which are selected by user